# How to create multiple threads for each request item

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to process the below code using multithreading at the order level.

```
List<String> orders = Arrays.asList("order1", "order2", 
                   "order3", "order4", "order1");
```

**Current sequential execution:**

```
orders.stream().forEach(order -> {
    rules.forEach(rule -> {
        finalList.add(beanMapper.getBean(rule)
                .applyRule(createTemplate.apply(getMetaData.apply(rule), command),
                           order));
    });
});
```

I have tried using:

```
orders.parallelStream().forEach(order -> {}} // code snippet.
```

But it is changing the **rules.forEach(rule -> {}}** order.

For example: 
Input :

```
 List<String> orders = Arrays.asList("order1", "order2", 
                         "order3", "order4", "order1");
 List<String> rules = Arrays.asList("rule1", "rule2", "rule3");
```

Expected output:

```
order1 with rule1, rule2, rule3
order2 with rule1, rule2, rule3
```

Actual output with `parallelStream()`:

```
order1 with rule3, rule1, rule2
order1 with rule2, rule1, rule3
```

I am not bothered about the order of **orders**, but I am bothered about eh order of **rules**.
Orders can process in any order, but rules should execute in the same order for each order.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
orders.stream().parallel().forEachOrdered(// Your rules logic goes here. )
```

**ForEachOrdered guarantees to maintain the order of the Stream.**

So for your reference:

```
orders.stream().parallel().forEachOrdered( order -> {

            rules.stream().parallel().forEachOrdered ( rule -> {

                 System.out.println( " Order : " + order + " rule :" + rule);
            });

        });
```

**Note :** While we can do this , performance should be closely watched because parellelism and order do not marry each other very well!

**Output**

```
 Order : order1 rule :rule1
 Order : order1 rule :rule2
 Order : order1 rule :rule3
 Order : order2 rule :rule1
 Order : order2 rule :rule2
 Order : order2 rule :rule3
 Order : order3 rule :rule1
 Order : order3 rule :rule2
 Order : order3 rule :rule3
 Order : order4 rule :rule1
 Order : order4 rule :rule2
 Order : order4 rule :rule3
 Order : order1 rule :rule1
 Order : order1 rule :rule2
 Order : order1 rule :rule3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. forEachOrdered guarantees the order of stream, but then it also slows down the performance. I tried it & the application is taking time similar to sequential processing. stream().parallel & forEachOrdered doesn't compliment each other.

Comment: Yup I agree we need to do full  latency analysis before doing this.

Comment: Yup, I am getting the same performance using this, there is no improvement.

Comment: Closely following this thread to get better solution to do this.

Comment: Can I achieve parallel processing using ExecutorService?

Comment: Yup you can ! Thats traditional way of doing that!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204719/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-pramod-nikam).

Comment: I tried that as well, but orders were getting processed in an only a single thread.

Comment: "**Please use**" are strong words for immediate re-sequentialising a parallel stream without doing anything parallel at all. "You could use, but it has no gain" would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You add elements to the `finalList` from different threads at the same time. This is causing mixing results of applying rules to different orders (rules aren't being grouped by their orders).

You can fix it by creating a temporary list for each `order` and then synchronously merging all temporary lists in a `finalList`.

Here is how you can do it using Stream-API (Java 9+):

```
List<AppliedRule> finalList = orders.parallelStream().map(order ->
        rules.stream().map(rule -> applyRule(order, rule)).collect(Collectors.toList())
).collect(Collectors.flatMapping(Collection::stream, Collectors.toList()));
```

Note: `Collectors.flatMapping()` is used here instead of simple `flatMap` to run flat mapping synchronously during stream collection.

---

Java 8 analog:

```
List<AppliedRule> finalList = orders.parallelStream().map(order ->
        rules.stream().map(rule -> applyRule(order, rule)).collect(Collectors.toList())
).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your approach & I am getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Comment: finalList = orders.parallelStream()
    .map(order -> rules.stream()
      .map(rule -> beanMapper.getBean(rule)
        .applyRule(createTemplate.apply(getMetaData.apply(rule), command), order))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @mayankbisht, this means that `beanMapper.getBean(rule) .applyRule(createTemplate.apply(getMetaData.apply(rule), command), order)` isn't a pure function, so it can't be used in parallel. Try to remove all the side effects from it; `ConcurrentModificationException` stack trace can help to locate them.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
final int rulesSize = rules.size();
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
orders.stream().parallel().forEach(order -> {
    IntStream.range(0, rulesSize).parallel().forEach( i -> {
        synchronized (atomicInteger) {
            System.out.println(" Order : " + order + " rule :" + rules.get(atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() % rulesSize));
        }
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
 Order : order1 rule :rule1
 Order : order4 rule :rule2
 Order : order1 rule :rule3
 Order : order3 rule :rule1
 Order : order3 rule :rule2
 Order : order3 rule :rule3
 Order : order2 rule :rule1
 Order : order2 rule :rule2
 Order : order2 rule :rule3
 Order : order1 rule :rule1
 Order : order1 rule :rule2
 Order : order4 rule :rule3
 Order : order1 rule :rule1
 Order : order4 rule :rule2
 Order : order1 rule :rule3
```

Answer (score 0):

> The order of orders can be anything, but the order of rules should not change. Also for a particular order rule should come in a group.

If that is the case, there is no room for actual parallelism.

When

> ```
> order1-rule1
> order1-rule2
> order2-rule1
> order2-rule2
> ```

and

> ```
> order2-rule1
> order2-rule2
> order1-rule1
> order1-rule2
> ```

are the only valid runs for 2 orders and 2 rules,
and

> ```
> order1-rule1
> order2-rule1
> order1-rule2
> order2-rule2
> ```

is considered invalid, that is not parallelism, just randomization of `order`s, presumably without gain. If you are "bored" with `order1` coming first all the time, you can shuffle the list, but that is all:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> orders = Arrays.asList("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4");
    List<String> rules = Arrays.asList("rule1", "rule2", "rule3");
    Collections.shuffle(orders);
    orders.forEach(order->{
        rules.forEach(rule->{
            System.out.println(order+"-"+rule);
        });
    });
}
```

Not even streaming is necessary, just two nested loops. Test: https://ideone.com/qI3dqd

> ```
> order2-rule1
> order2-rule2
> order2-rule3
> order4-rule1
> order4-rule2
> order4-rule3
> order1-rule1
> order1-rule2
> order1-rule3
> order3-rule1
> order3-rule2
> order3-rule3
> ```

---

**Original answer**

> But it is changing the rules.forEach(rule -> {}} order.

No, it does not. The `order`s may overlap, but the order of `rule`s for each order are kept. Why would a non-parallel `forEach` do anything else?

Example code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> orders = Arrays.asList("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4");
    List<String> rules = Arrays.asList("rule1", "rule2", "rule3");
    orders.stream().parallel().forEach(order->{
        rules.forEach(rule->{
            System.out.println(order+"-"+rule);
        });
    });
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/95Cybg
Example output:

> ```
> order2-rule1
> order2-rule2
> order2-rule3
> order1-rule1
> order1-rule2
> order1-rule3
> order4-rule1
> order4-rule2
> order4-rule3
> order3-rule1
> order3-rule2
> order3-rule3
> ```

The order of `order`s is mixed, but the `rule`s are always 1-2-3. I think your output simply hid the pairings (actually you did not show how it was generated).

Of course it can be extended with some delays, so processing of `order`s will actually overlap:

```
public static void delay(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100,300));
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> orders = Arrays.asList("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4");
    List<String> rules = Arrays.asList("rule1", "rule2", "rule3");
    orders.stream().parallel().forEach(order->{
        rules.forEach(rule->{
            delay();
            System.out.println(order+"-"+rule);
        });
    });
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/cSFaqS
Example output:

> ```
> order3-rule1
> order2-rule1
> order2-rule2
> order3-rule2
> order3-rule3
> order2-rule3
> order1-rule1
> order4-rule1
> order1-rule2
> order4-rule2
> order4-rule3
> order1-rule3
> ```

This may be something what you have seen, just without the `orderx` part. With the `order`s visible it can be tracked that `rule`s keep coming as 1-2-3, *per `order`*. Also, your example list contained `order1` twice which for sure did not help in seeing what was happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above output may be correct for less number of orders. But if you increase the orders, then you will get a different output. For ex.(order4-rule1
order4-rule2
order4-rule1)
(order1-rule1
 order1-rule2)
(order3-rule1
order3-rule2)
(order4-rule1
order4-rule2
order4-rule1
order4-rule2).

Comment: The order of orders can be anything, but the order of rules should not change. Also for a particular order rule should come in a group. For ex. (order1- rule 1 order1-rule2 order1-rule3) and not  (order1-rule1 order2-rule1 order1-rule2 order1-rule3).)

Comment: @mayankbisht I think these restrictions simply do not allow parallel processing. See updated answer (I wrote the new part at the beginning).

Comment: Yup, I do understand that, and that's why I posted this question here. I thought maybe there will another way of doing this, or maybe we can change the algo

Comment: @mayankbisht you could describe why `order`s can not overlap (are those `rule`s stateful perhaps, and existing in a limited number of copies, perhaps a single one only?). But generally there is no parallelism without things running in parallel, that is the whole point of parallelism after all.

Comment: Sure, the thing is the downstream system is expecting data in that format. According to their specifications, the order can come in any order but associated rules should maintain the order. Again for ex. if we have 3 orders, then (order1-rule1 order-rule2 order-rule3),(order3-rule1 order3-rule2 order3-rule3) is fine, but (order1-rule3 order1-rule1 order1-rule2) is not allowed.

Comment: @mayankbisht consider adding this downstream system requirement to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to try third-party library. Here is sample with my library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
StreamEx.of(orders).parallelStream().forEach(order -> {}}
```

And you can even specify the thread number:

```
StreamEx.of(orders).parallelStream(maxThreadNum).forEach(order -> {}}
```

The order of `rule` will be kept.

By the way, since it's in parallel stream, the piece of code `...finalList.add(...` most likely won't work. I think it's better to collect the result to list:

```
StreamEx.of(orders).parallelStream().map/flatMap(order -> {...}}.toList()
```

it's also doable even if you want to keep the order of `order` for some reason later:

```
StreamEx.of(orders).indexed().parallelStream()
      .map/flatMap(order -> {...}}.sortedBy(...index).toList()
```